# Seagate Exos dying? SMART-Tool headless from Seagte?

Tags: smartctl, seagate

I have a software RAID under Ubuntu 20.04. One disk (Seagate ST1800MM0129) is marked as faulty, thus I run smartctl with this result

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdd
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-166-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST1800MM0129
Revision:             C003
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        1.800.360.124.416 bytes [1,80 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Rotation Rate:        10500 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c500c1d0c303
Serial number:        removed
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Thu Nov 16 11:47:08 2023 CET
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Grown defects during certification <not available>
Total blocks reassigned during format <not available>
Total new blocks reassigned <not available>
Power on minutes since format <not available>
Current Drive Temperature:     31 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        60 C

Manufactured in week 21 of year 2019
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  39
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  1498
Elements in grown defect list: 93

Vendor (Seagate Cache) information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 24
  Blocks received from initiator = 72
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 0
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 1
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 0

Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 33270,17
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 58

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:       9292        0         0      9292          0          0,000           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0          0,268           0

Non-medium error count:        0


[GLTSD (Global Logging Target Save Disable) set. Enable Save with '-S on']
SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background long   Completed                   -   33247                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self-test duration: 9459 seconds [157,7 minutes]
```

Is this enough for warranty ( Elements in grown defect list: 93 ) or do I need a special Seagate tool? I didn't found a special Seagate Smart tool for Linux without graphical interface, just for command line

Comment: The "Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds" table is missing. Did you omit it from the post or did `smartctl` omit it from the report?

Comment: I posted the whole output of smartctl -a /dev/sdd